# Print Top 6 Results from a List

Tags: c#, list, for-loop

I need to print a list that puts together  the top 6 results from a patient list I ordered using

```
 public enum PatientPriority { Magenta = 0, Red = 1, Yellow = 2, Green = 3 };
```

and my Medic List.

I think this is doable by using this code:

```
foreach (var doctor in myDoctorList)
{
    if (sortedPatients.Count == 0)
        break; //no more patients

    var patient = sortedPatients[0];
    sortedPatients.RemoveAt(0); //remove the patient from the listing/queue

    doctor.AssignedPatient = patient;
}
```

Im just not sure how do I retrieve "sortedPatients".
This is my medic list.

```
        //MedicList
        MedicList.Add(new Medic(01, "Antonio", 555444333, "antonio@gmail.com", "Dermatologista"));
        MedicList.Add(new Medic(02, "Lucas", 555444333, "lucas78@gmail.com", "Cardiologista"));
        MedicList.Add(new Medic(03, "Duarte", 555444333, "Duarte90@gmail.com", "Otorrino"));
        MedicList.Add(new Medic(04, "Marcos", 555444333, "marcos123@gmail.com", "Clinica Geral"));
        MedicList.Add(new Medic(05, "Pedro", 555444333, "Pedro12@gmail.com", "Pediatra"));
        MedicList.Add(new Medic(06, "Pedro", 555444333, "Pedro12@gmail.com", "Urologia"));
```

And this is My Pacient list that uses random colors.

```
        // - ListaUtentes (presentes no Centro de Saúde)
        ListaUtente.Add(new Utente(100001, "Pedro", 914754123, "pedro@gmail.com", GetRandomColor()));
        ListaUtente.Add(new Utente(100002, "Lucas", 974123214, "lucas91@gmail.com", GetRandomColor()));
        ListaUtente.Add(new Utente(100003, "Rodrigo", 941201456, "rodrigo00@gmail.com", GetRandomColor()));
        ListaUtente.Add(new Utente(100004, "Gaspar", 987453210, "gaspar@gmail.com", GetRandomColor()));
        ListaUtente.Add(new Utente(100005, "Roberto", 974120219, "roberto@gmail.com", GetRandomColor()));
        ListaUtente.Add(new Utente(100006, "Eduardo", 974120219, "edu@gmail.com", GetRandomColor()));
        ListaUtente.Add(new Utente(100007, "Ismael", 974120219, "Isma@gmail.com", GetRandomColor()));
        ListaUtente.Add(new Utente(100008, "Paulo", 974120219, "Paulo90@gmail.com", GetRandomColor()));
        ListaUtente.Sort();
```

Can you help me with this? If someone needs to take a look at my Medic or Utente (sick people) class Atributes I can post them too.

Comment: quick question, what platform are you using? and do you just want to get a list of 6 entires with a specific priority so that you can push it for printing?

Comment: If you want the top 6 patients in your list after you have ordered the list it is simply this: _ListaUtente.Take(6)_

Comment: what platform is it? that's a more important question

Comment: @AdityaSharma Im using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: @Steve Yes but I need it to print those 6 top results plus the 6 medics on my medic list.

Comment: Platform not IDE. Is it Windows Phone? or Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) or WCF or UWP? according to that we'll be able to help you

Comment: You should provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: ListaUtente.Take(6)(Console.WriteLine) wouldn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a stab at what I think you are asking, the top 6 patients listed in order of color assuming magenta is highest priority and green lowest.  I also filled out some of the things you left out with the hopes that this will get you in the right direction: I made up the properties of Utente and just filled in the priority color instead of generating them randomly.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.Linq;

public enum PatientPriority { Magenta = 0, Red = 1, Yellow = 2, Green = 3 }; 

public class Utente
{
    public int Id{get; set;}
    public string Name{get; set;}
    public int Key{get; set;}
    public string Email{get; set;}
    public PatientPriority Priority{get; set;}

    public Utente(int id, string name, int key, string email, PatientPriority priority)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Key = key;
        Email = email;
        Priority = priority;
    }

}

public class Test
{

    public static void Main()
{

        var ListaUtente = new List<Utente>(); 
        ListaUtente.Add(new Utente(100001, "Pedro", 914754123, "pedro@gmail.com", PatientPriority.Yellow));
        ListaUtente.Add(new Utente(100002, "Lucas", 974123214, "lucas91@gmail.com", PatientPriority.Green));
        ListaUtente.Add(new Utente(100003, "Rodrigo", 941201456, "rodrigo00@gmail.com", PatientPriority.Yellow));
        ListaUtente.Add(new Utente(100004, "Gaspar", 987453210, "gaspar@gmail.com", PatientPriority.Red));
        ListaUtente.Add(new Utente(100005, "Roberto", 974120219, "roberto@gmail.com", PatientPriority.Magenta));
        ListaUtente.Add(new Utente(100006, "Eduardo", 974120219, "edu@gmail.com", PatientPriority.Red));
        ListaUtente.Add(new Utente(100007, "Ismael", 974120219, "Isma@gmail.com", PatientPriority.Green));
        ListaUtente.Add(new Utente(100008, "Paulo", 974120219, "Paulo90@gmail.com", PatientPriority.Yellow));

        Console.WriteLine("Unsorted:");
        foreach (var u in ListaUtente)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("id: " + u.Id + " Priority: " + u.Priority);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Sorted: ");
        foreach(var su in ListaUtente.OrderBy(u => u.Priority).Take(6).ToList())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("id: " + su.Id + " Priority: " + su.Priority);
        }

}
}
```

Comment: I have an error on this line: Console.WriteLine("id: " + u.Id + " Priority: " + u.Priority); On u.Priority. - Error 1 'GESTUR.Medico' does not contain a definition for 'PatientPriority' and no extension method 'PatientPriority' accepting a first argument of type 'GESTUR.Medico' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Answer (score 0):

```
var sortedPatients = ListaUtente.OrderBy(u => u.NameOfPriorityProperty).Take(6).ToList();
```

If you want all patients (not only top 6), then remove `Take` step.

Comment: But in order to display the result would I need a Console.WriteLine?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign the first 6 patients to the first 6 medics is better to use a simply for...loop.
The list class can be iterated as it was a normal array

```
int topCount = 6;
var sortedPatients = ListaUtente.OrderBy(x => x.Priority).ToList();
for(int x = 0; x < topCount; x++)
{
   MedicList[x].AssignedPatient  = sortedPatients[x];
   Console.WriteLine($"Utente:{sortedPatients[x].Name}, Priority:{sortedPatients[x].Priority}");
}
```

Of course this assumes that both lists have at least 6 entries

Comment: Wouldn't I need a Console.WriteLine to display my results on screen?

Comment: Yes it depends by the type of your application. In a console application you use Console.WriteLine. WinForms have forms and label or listbox and so on.

Comment: But I have an error on AssignedPatient, should I replace it with something else?

Comment: I can't tell you what the problem is. If you add the classes Medic and Utente to your question perhaps it will be more clear (Do not forget to report the error message received)